# No module named helpers

Tags: python, tensorflow

I trying to **import helpers** when I run [this tutorial](https://github.com/ematvey/tensorflow-seq2seq-tutorials/blob/master/1-seq2seq.ipynb)
. However, this reported a error: ImportError: No module named helpers. I can't find any proper package in pypi. How can I get the third party package?

The following is the tutorial fragment

```
In [1]:
x = [[5, 7, 8], [6, 3], [3], [1]]
While manipulating such variable-length lists are convenient to humans, RNNs prefer a different layout:
In [2]:
import helpers
xt, xlen = helpers.batch(x)
In [3]:
x
Out[3]:
[[5, 7, 8], [6, 3], [3], [1]]
In [4]:
xt
Out[4]:
array([[5, 6, 3, 1],
       [7, 3, 0, 0],
       [8, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

[image: Codes following]

Notes: **Helpers is not Helper**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `helpers` module you're looking for, is created by the creator of the tutorial you linked.

(It's not one of the tensorflow package), you can get the helpers module by either cloning the entire GitHub [repository](https://github.com/ematvey/tensorflow-seq2seq-tutorials) or downloading only the [`helpers.py`](https://github.com/ematvey/tensorflow-seq2seq-tutorials/blob/master/helpers.py).